# Youth associations in Turkey

Tags: europe, online-resources, turkey, ankara

I am looking for youth/students associations in Turkey, especially associations with an interest in Europe.

I'm currently writing articles about these subjects ([link to my website here](http://europenextdoor.com/en/)) and would like to meet new people there.

Every tips and advises are welcome.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about journalism rather than travel.